# How to avoid manually caching a request that returned an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, module-pattern

I've created a module (following Javascript's Module Pattern) that makes an http request, caches and returns the result:

```
var requestService = (function($) {

    var cache = {};

    var get = function(date) {
        var params = date ? {'date': date} : {};
        return $.getJSON('http://my/url', params, function( result ){});
    };

    var fetchData = function(date) {
        if (!cache[date]) {
            cache[date] = get(date);
        }

        return cache[date].done(function(myData) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
                resolve(myData);
            });
        });
    };

    return {
        fetchData: fetchData
    };
})(jQuery);
```

My problem is that the results are cached even if there's an error (ex: the host is temporary unreachable). I don't want that to happen.

I thought that the done() function would only be called if the request succeeded, but it's not the case. Should I add a cache[date].fail(), setting itself to null? What I mean:

```
return cache[date].done(function(myData) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        resolve(myData);
    });
}).fail(function(myData) {
    cache[date] = null;
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        reject(myData);
    });
});
```

Here's how my requestService is called in another module:

```
requestService.fetchData(myDate).done(function(myData) {
    // code when successful
}).fail(function(d, textStats, error) {
    // error
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`done` and `fail` do not support chaining callback results, your `return new Promise` is absolutely pointless. Also it looks as if you are trying to use the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). What your code does it to simply return the ajax promise as-is (which works, as you can chain onto it).

> the results are cached even if there's an error

Yes - by storing the promise, the whole request result is cached, not only in the success case.

> Should I add a rejection handler, setting itself to null?

Yes, that's exactly what you'll need to do:

```
var requestService = (function($) {
    var cache = {};

    function get(date) {
        var params = date ? {'date': date} : {};
        return $.getJSON('http://my/url', params);
    }

    function fetchData(date) {
        if (!cache[date]) {
            cache[date] = get(date);
            cache[date].fail(function(err) {
                cache[date] = null; // retry next time
            });
        }
        return cache[date];
    }

    return {
        fetchData: fetchData
    };
})(jQuery);
```

If you want to return a native promise, use

```
function fetchData(date) {
    if (!cache[date]) {
        cache[date] = Promise.resolve(get(date)).catch(function(err) {
            cache[date] = null; // retry next time
            throw err;
        });
    }
    return cache[date];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up! I am indeed new to the promise API, this code is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

ok nevermind, that code worked with some adjustments. In my fetchData method I'm checking if the object is empty (so undefined *or* null) and I've added a fail() method that nullifies the cache[date]. I do the following now:

```
var requestService = (function($) {

    var cache = {};

    var get = function(date) {
        var params = date ? {'date': date} : {};
        return $.getJSON('http://my/url', params, function( result ){});
    };

    var fetchData = function(date) {
        // now also checks for null
        if ($.isEmptyObject(cache[date])) {
            cache[date] = get(date);
        }

        return cache[date].done(function(myData) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
                resolve(myData);
            });
        }).fail(function(myData) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            // nullifies cache[date]
            cache[date] = null;
            reject(myData);
        });
    };

    return {
        fetchData: fetchData
    };
})(jQuery);
```