# Creating an async singletone in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, singleton

I need to implement an async singleton, that creates a single instance of a class that requires asynchronous operations in order to pass arguments to the constructor.
I have the following code:

```
class AsyncComp {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // A factory method for creating the async instance
    static async createAsyncInstance() {
        const info = await someAsyncFunction();
        return new AsyncComp(info.x, info.y);
    }

    // The singleton method
    static getAsyncCompInstance() {
        if (asyncCompInstance) return asyncCompInstance;
        asyncCompInstance = AsyncComp.createAsyncInstance();
        return asyncCompInstance;
    }
}
```

The code seems to work fine, as long as the promise fulfils. If, however, the promise is rejected the next calls to `getAsyncCompInstance()` will return the unfulfilled promise object, which means that it will not be possible to retry the creation of the object.
How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't see any reason, if the promise is properly rejected, it should work. Can we also check `someAsyncFunction`?

Comment: @sjahan even if the promise is rejected, asyncCompInstance is not null anymore, so getAsyncCompInstance() returns it instead of continue to the next line that calls createAsyncInstance()

Comment: if `someAsyncFunction` throws an error the next line will not be executed and hence no instance will be returned. You could put a try catch in static method and return null in case of error.

Comment: @AshishModi, this is not accurate. getAsyncCompInstance() does not await createAsyncInstance(), it returns the promise immediately. The code that calls getAsyncCompInstance() takes care of the error handling, and if getAsyncCompInstance() throws/rejects, this code will catch it.

Comment: my bad. totally missed the "does not wait" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after thinking about a couple of possible solution, I decided to wrap the asynchronous call in `createAsyncInstance()` with a `try/catch` block, and if it failed, set `asyncCompInstance` back to be null, and throw the error the occurred. This way, if the object creation failed, the caller can call `getAsyncCompInstance()` again to try to get an instance of the class:

```
class AsyncComp {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // A factory method for creating the async instance
    static async createAsyncInstance() {
        try {
            const info = await someAsyncFunction();
            return new AsyncComp(info.x, info.y);
        }
        catch (err) {
            asyncCompInstance = null;
            throw err;
        }
    }

    // The singleton method
    static getAsyncCompInstance() {
        if (asyncCompInstance) return asyncCompInstance;
        asyncCompInstance = AsyncComp.createAsyncInstance();
        return asyncCompInstance;
    }
}
```

I know this is not the cleanest code, and specifically not the classic factory pattern implementation, but this is the best I could come up with at the moment. Would love to hear comments/suggestions on this solution.

Comment: The approach is fine (similar to [what I would do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018394/1048572)), but for cleanliness I'd move the `try`/`catch` into the `getAsyncCompInstance` method whose job it is to store the singleton. Or really just merge them into a single method, as you never would want to call `createAsyncInstance` individually (ignoring the singleton).

Comment: A further refactor might move the `new AsyncComp` call outside of the `try` block - you would only want to handle errors from `someAsyncFunction`, but retrying because the constructor failed might be pointless. Continuing on that, you could just move the retry logic inside of the `someAsyncFunction`, and keep an eventual rejection as the final value. But this depends a lot on your usage scenario, if there are multiple call sites of `getAsyncCompInstance()` and you think it is not flexible enough to share their error handling then you might better avoid a singleton altogether.